# Mvc UrlHelper in conjunction with JQuery Templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encoding, jquery-templates, urlhelper

I would like to use the Mvc UrlHelper in conjunction with JQuery Templates.

Example template...

```
...
{{each Items}}        
    <div>
        <%= Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { Id = "${$value.Id}" })%>
    </div> 
{{/each}}
...
```

The Url helper Action method encodes the template placeholder that I pass in as the Id parameter. This renders as..

```
...
<div>
    /web/controller/%24%7B%24value.Id%7D/action
</div>
<div>
    /web/controller/%24%7B%24value.Id%7D/action
</div>
...
```

I could really do with a way to prevent the Action method from encoding the Id parameter value, but I suppose it’s only doing its job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately its by design and you'll have to work around it - see Rick Strahl's post on this

http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/831885.aspx

Comment: one thing I never tried though was to wrap  "${$value.Id}"  in new HtmlString( "${$value.Id}" )

Comment: Nice idea with the HtmlString, but that didn't work unfortunately. I guess the Action method doesn't check for that type of object before encoding it. We will probably end up creating our own version of the helper for use with templates but haven't done so yet.

Comment: should be easy to adapt too since the source is available : )